# Why does my laptop freeze up a few minutes after the power cable is disconnected?

Tags: bios, freeze, battery

If the computer is running on wall-power and power cable is then disconnected, which sometimes happens accidentally, the computer will freeze up within a few minutes unless I notice and quickly reattach the cable. If, however, I boot the computer without the power cable connected, it runs fine on battery power until running out of juice.

Could this be a driver issue? I'd very much prefer not to have to mail it in for repair, even though it is still covered under warranty. In fact, if it's definitely a hardware issue that I can't fix on my own, I'll probably just deal with it as is.

Laptop Specifications : http://bit.ly/t654iH

---

Oh, and when the computer freezes the CPU utilization raises up to 100% and the only process with max. CPU utilization is '***svchost.exe***'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would think it could be a driver issue.  Typically you'd be looking at a chipset driver (many times in laptops the default windows driver will do enough for the stuff to not show an issue in Devman but maybe not function FULLY and in these cases battery/power issues seem common).

I would:

- Download and install the most current chipset drivers for your system from HP.
- Double check Devman to ensure nothing is noting an issue and fix any you see the same as above.
- Ensure the battery does have a full proper charge.

If none of these work … maybe starting changing some of your power settings one at a time.  Starting with OS and if need be working back to BIOS settings.

As an ace in the hole…

- Flash the BIOS.

Technically I don't see how this would help but I have seen weirder stuff work for weirder issues.  Flashing the BIOS is technically no big deal but there is risk which is why I label it as an "ace in the hole".  Play it at your own risk.

That's about all I can suggest.

Comment: Sometimes the vendor install weird power profile, accessible on the batter icon in the task bar. Try and select `Always On` or `High performance` and use advanced setting to tweak to your liking. Vendor power profiles can cause issues sometimes.